# EF code first FLUENT: many to many with additional field in jointable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first, fluent

I'm building a wiki, which has articles that consists of subarticles. An article can consist of multiple subarticles, and a subarticle can be attached to multiple articles. In the jointable there is a sortorder that defines the display of subarticles for a particular article.
The parent-article only consists of a title (and metadata), no text, all text is done through subarticles.

This sortorder in the jointable though, is where I'm stuck atm, I can't access it from my query. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Sidenote: I'm quite new in the whole MVC/EF world, even c#/vb and .NET is something I've only been working on since a few months and in my spare time.

I have these classes:

***Article:***

```
public class Article : BaseEntity
{

    private ICollection<Category> _categories;
    private ICollection<ArticleSubarticle> _subarticles;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ?PublishDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ?ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return _categories ?? (_categories = new List<Category>()); }
        protected set { _categories = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleSubarticle> Subarticles
    {
        get { return _subarticles ?? (_subarticles = new List<ArticleSubarticle>()); }
        protected set { _subarticles = value; }
    }

}
```

***Subarticle***

```
public class Subarticle : Article
    {

        private ICollection<Attachment> _attachments;

        public string ArticleText { get; set; }
        public int OriginalArticle { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments
        {
            get { return _attachments ?? (_attachments = new List<Attachment>()); }
            protected set { _attachments = value; }
        }

    }
```

***Jointable:***

```
public class ArticleSubarticle : BaseEntity
    {

        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int ChildId { get; set; }

        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public virtual Article Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual Subarticle Child { get; set; }

    }
```

They are mapped as follows:

***Article***

```
public ArticleMap () {

            ToTable("Wiki_Article");

            HasKey(a => a.Id);
            Property(a => a.Title).HasColumnType("VARCHAR").HasMaxLength(250);
            Property(a => a.AuthorId);
            Property(a => a.PublishDate).IsOptional();
            Property(a => a.ChangeDate).IsOptional();

            HasMany(a => a.Categories)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("Wiki_Article_Category_Mapping"));



        }
```

***Subarticle***

```
public SubarticleMap()
        {

            ToTable("Wiki_Subarticle");
            HasKey(sa => sa.Id);

            Property(a => a.ArticleText)
                .IsOptional()
                .HasColumnType("TEXT");

            Property(a => a.OriginalArticle)
                .IsOptional();

            HasMany(a => a.Attachments)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("Wiki_Subarticle_Attachment_Mapping"));

        }
```

***Jointable***

```
public ArticleSubarticleMap()
        {

            ToTable("Wiki_Article_Subarticle_Mapping");

            HasKey(asa => new { asa.ParentId, asa.ChildId });

            HasRequired(asa => asa.Parent)
                .WithMany(asa => asa.Subarticles)
                .HasForeignKey(asa => asa.ParentId);

        }
```

This gets me the database as expected.

Now I want an article with its subarticles, that are ordered by the sortorder.
This query gets me the article with its subarticles, but I can't seem to figure out how to reach this sortorder in the Wiki_Article_Subarticle_Mapping table.

```
public IList<Article> getArticleByIdWithSortedSubarticles(int ArticleId)
        {
            var query = _articleRepository.Table;
            query = query.Where(a => ArticleId == a.Id)
                         .Select(a => a);

            var subarticles = query.ToList();

            return subarticles;

        }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not loading subarticles currently, so I guess they are lazily loaded. Try loading them explicitly like this:

```
public IList<Article> getArticleByIdWithSortedSubarticles(int ArticleId)
{
    var query = _articleRepository.Table;
    query = query.Where(a => ArticleId == a.Id)
                 .Select(a => new { article = a, subs = a.SubArticles.OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder) });

    return query.AsEnumerable().Select(m => m.article).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The subarticles are getting loaded though (I assume through the relation that is defined?)
In any case I do get a list of my subarticles back...

Comment: Yes because you made your `Subarticles` collection `virtual`, which enables lazy loading. But this will not guarantee any ordering.

Comment: Well, I've tried your suggestion, and the strange thing now is, that I get an error on the a.SubArticles ('Article does not contain a definition for SubArticles and no extension method SubArticles accepting a first argument of type Article could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference').
But when I type your suggestion (instead of copypaste), VS auto-complete DOES give me a.SubArticles and when I hover a, he definately recognizes it as parameter Article.
Any suggestions here?

Comment: I don't know enough about your repositories, esp. the `_articleRepository.Table` part. Maybe you should consider passing your `DbContext` along as a parameter to your queries, and then do something like this `context.Articles.Where(...`